# jquery javascript chrome/safari issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am using the following javascript to pull in a 'back to top' button when scrolling down.

This works great on Firefox - but doesn't work on Chrome/Safari.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#totop").hide();
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            jQuery('#totop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            jQuery('#totop').fadeOut();
        }
    });
            
    jQuery('#totop').click(function(){
        jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 660, 'easeInOutExpo');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo site http://demov3.joostrap.com

I have tried using noConflict.

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome or FF.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: Check your console for exceptions...: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return document.id(a,b,this.document)} has no method 'noConflict'`. Chrome 32.0.1664.3 canary

Comment: no... don't get any errors in Chrome Inspector

Comment: j08691 - i was just trying something - try FF now

Comment: looks like some dodgy rendering issue...

Comment: The problem lies on the `position: fixed` and the use of `z-index`. If you inspect the page, you'll notice the link is actually there, but somehow "invisible". That's a known Google Chrome (and some other Webkit browsers) issue.

Comment: MelanciaUK - do you know of any easy fix?

Comment: I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, there's a known issue with Google Chrome and some other WebKit browsers regarding fixed position and z-index.

Checking your page source, I would recommend the following changes:

```
<-- Set the body element z-index value to 0 (inline or 
    on the CSS stylesheet) -->
<body class="com_content view-featured layout- task- frontpage itemid-101 no-rtl" style="z-index: 0;">

    <div class="body-wrapper">
        ...
    </div>

    <-- Stick the link as the last element within the body element, and change
        its z-index value to 9999 (on the CSS stylesheet) -->
    <a href="#" id="totop"></a>
</body>
```

Comment: MelanciaUK - thanks... but still no joy! edited as you advised.

Comment: god dammit... found the issue - removing the z-index:-999; on '.joostrapslider-container' & '#slider' fixed the issue